# DNS update port(s)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

What ports are required for a DC (Windows 2012 R2) to be able to create / update SRV records? It doesn't appear to be working for my system(s) and I'm trying to debug the process.

`dcdiag /test:DNS` reports 'all DNS servers are invalid'. The IPs are correct so I'm wondering whether there is a closed/firewalled port somewhere.

---

EDIT:

> C:\Users\Administrator>nltest /dsregdns
>   Flags: 0
>   Connection Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
>   The command completed successfully

No updates found on the DNS.

Comment: 53.  Unless you're using secure updates, in which case you've got RPC, LDAP and Kerberos ports in the mix too.

Comment: @ethrbunny: Does nltest /dsregdns create the records?

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory Integrated DNS uses standard AD replication for DNS as well, since the zone contents are stored in the directory much like users and computers are.

For a complete list of ports that you should have open on your domain controllers, check the official TechNet documentation - it's quite a long list. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I don't know that the DNS server is using AD. Is there some way to test externally?

Comment: Are your DNS servers running on domain controllers? Are they set to "Active Directory Integrated"?

Comment: Not running on DCs. Appears to be running 'Lucent DNS 5.x'.

Comment: In that case, this has nothing to do with Windows Server, as Lucent DNS (whatever that is) is not part of Windows Server and is a third party product. Have you read the Lucent DNS documentation? Start there.

Comment: Right - my original question was whether or not I needed to open specific ports to be able to add SRV records from my DC.

Comment: How are you configuring your DC to update these records? Why aren't you hosting DNS on the DCs with the Windows DNS Server role?

Comment: Big company. Centralized user accounting. Created a subdomain. Ultimate goal is to authenticate using the centralized LDAP server. Need a working AD domain first.